# How to pass number to TextField JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am working on simple calculator, where users input two numbers in `TextField` and the result is displayed in result `TextField`. I used `Double.parseDouble` to get the text from input TextFields and apply the operation on it. But I am unable to pass it to third input field. I tried to cast back the `double` result to String but It didn't work. How can I simply pass number to TextField?

```
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(numberInput1.getText());
double num2 = Double.parseDouble(numberInput2.getText());
double resultV = (num1 + num2);

resultInput.setText(resultV);
```

The last line is not working and as the format is different.

Comment: Use `String.valueOf(resultV)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method `TextField.setText (double)`

try

```
resultInput.setText("" + resultV);
```

but I guess what you really want is for the result to be nicely formatted to maybe two decimal places?

try using

```
resultInput.setText(String.format ("%6.2f", resultV));
```

Answer (score 2):

`setText` expects a `String` as parameter. You need to convert the result to a `String`, e.g. by using `Double.toString`.

However in this case I recommend adding a [`TextFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) to the `TextField` which allows you to assign/input values of a type different to `String` using a `TextField`:

```
TextField summand1 = new TextField();
TextField summand2 = new TextField();
TextField result = new TextField();

StringConverter<Double> converter = new DoubleStringConverter();

TextFormatter<Double> tf1 = new TextFormatter<>(converter, 0d);
TextFormatter<Double> tf2 = new TextFormatter<>(converter, 0d);
TextFormatter<Double> tfRes = new TextFormatter<>(converter, 0d);

summand1.setTextFormatter(tf1);
summand2.setTextFormatter(tf2);
result.setTextFormatter(tfRes);

tfRes.valueProperty().bind(
        Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> tf1.getValue() + tf2.getValue(),
                tf1.valueProperty(),
                tf2.valueProperty()));

result.setEditable(false);
```

This allows you to assign the value using the `TextFormatter`, e.g.

```
double someValue = 3d;
tf1.setValue(someValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use 
`resultInput.setText(Double.toString(resultV));`